# Setting a range to current position in outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that inserts a table into the active e-mail. Now my problem is that i cant figure out how to add the table where the user is typing when he runs the macro. I think I have to define a range, and I've looked into the collapse method but I'm stuck.

This is my code:

```
sub insertmytable() <br>
Dim oRng As Object <br> 
Dim wdDoc As Object<br>
  If TypeName(ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then<br>
   If ActiveInspector.IsWordMail And ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then<br>
    Set wdDoc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor<br>
    With wdDoc<br>
     Set oRng = wdDoc.Range<br>
     oRng.collapse<br>
     .tables.Add Range:=oRng, numrows:=2, numcolumns:=5, defaulttablebehavior:=1, autofitbehavior:=0<br>
    end with<br>
   end if<br>
 end if<br>
end sub<br>
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try working with .InsertBefore

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx

```
Sub PasteAtInsertionPoint()

Dim objOL As Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objSel As Word.Selection

Dim strText As String

Set objOL = Outlook.Application
Set objDoc = objOL.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

strText = " Test"
objSel.InsertBefore strText

End Sub
```

Edit 2014 11 17

```
Sub insertmytable()

Dim oRng As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object

Dim objSel As Word.Selection

If TypeName(ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then

    If ActiveInspector.IsWordMail And ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then

        Set wdDoc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
        Set objSel = wdDoc.Windows(1).Selection
        Set oRng = objSel.Range
        oRng.Tables.Add Range:=oRng, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=5, DefaultTableBehavior:=1, AutoFitBehavior:=0

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks niton. This way I can insert text just at the insertion point. But how do I add a table using .InsertBefore?

Comment: Yes! This gave me the "user defined type not defined" at first, but then I added the Microsoft Word 14.0 Object library under tools -> references and now it works perfectly. Thank you!